# When storing data into a file, what's the difference between error_log() and file_put_contents()?

Tags: php

I was wondering what's the technical difference between these two:

```
error_log('test', 3, 'test.txt');
```

versus

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', 'test', FILE_APPEND);
```

They both seem to take the same amount of time, however.

Comment: I doubt there's any significant technical difference between the two, but the difference in usage is immense.

Comment: Maybe there is no technical difference between the two lines you show, but `error_log()` is infinitely more versatile - it can do a lot more than just write into a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically between `error_log('test', 3, 'test.txt')` and `file_put_contents('test.txt', 'test', FILE_APPEND)` there is no difference by what the documentation says ([file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)) as both will just append it to a file.

The main difference between the functions is that `error_log` can do more than log to a file with the ability to send to PHP's system logger, send the error as email or send it to the SAPI logging handler if you set either `0`, `1` or `4`.

Using `file_put_contents` does allowing specifying a string, array or stream resource whereas `error_log` only allows specifying a string as the message. This may have an impact depending what data you are wanting to log however your example is just a string so it doesn't hold any importance.

If, like in your example, you are writing a simple string error message to a file they will have the same end result. With that said though, I would recommend using `error_log` as it allows easier conversion later on to sending email messages and the function name better suits its task for future maintainers of the code.

If you are not intending to use it as for writing an error message (and I only say this because of the choice of words in the question title - "When storing *data*..." vs "When storing *errors*..."), I would recommend using `file_put_contents` for a similar reason in my paragraph above in that the function name better suits its task for future code maintainers.